# Free Java GUI Builder?

Tags: java, user-interface

I SUCK at using Layout Managers. I can never get anything right... so.. can anyone suggest to me free GUI builders for applets?

Do NOT suggest Eclipse or Netbeans because I have Vista (64-bit). I can't run them =(

Thanks!

Comment: why you can't run Eclipse or Netbeans on vista64???

Comment: Really you can't run Eclipse on Vista 64bit? Then change operating system :)

Comment: You can most certainly run those programs on Vista x64.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IDE for Swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458/ide-for-swing)

Comment: If you suck at layout managers, any GUI created using a GUI builder will suck even more.  GUI builders can be great, but they require an understanding of the layouts available, as well as how to use them.

Comment: @Andrew: depends on the layout. The more less flexibile layout managers can be infuriating to work with (because they *can't* do what you want), and the more flexible layout managers (e.g. flexible grids) can be much easier work with visually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NetBeans can [most certainly be installed](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqInstall64Bit) on 64-bit windows, but the 6.0.x versions required a 32-bit JVM. That doesn't seem to be the case anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I **would** recommend Netbeans, Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA as they are the most advanced designers.

But since you do not want them, maybe try [formlayoutmaker](http://formlayoutmaker.sourceforge.net/) (it is for JGoodies, however) ?

Why can't you run Eclipse in Vista 64, btw?

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend learning to use layout managers.  It is worth the effort even if it is difficult at the moment because they really are a foundational piece to GUIs in Java.

Two things that really helped me learn them:

1. The visual guide: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html
2. Learning that you could put one layout inside another layout, inside another layout, to achieve the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The one I like the most at the moment is the one in Netbeans.  6.9 should run on your system.

Answer (score 0):

[WindowBuilder Pro](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download.html) - It used to cost a not insignificant amount, but is now free because Google bought them.  It's an Eclipse plugin, but as everyone has said, Eclipse runs fine on 64-bit Windows.

I don't like the Netbeans GUI builder because you're locked in.  Anyone else that works with you needs to use it as well.  Auto-formatters also screw with it.  WindowBuilder is nice because it's able to work with existing code.

Really, if you're doing non-trivial Java work, an IDE will make things easier and faster for most people.